# Is there any way to break the limit of openCL memory in android？

Tags: android, arm, gpu, opencl

I want to allocate 4.5GB to my openCL program in android phone wiht 8GB memory.
But I found the memory size from `CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE` is much lower than the device memory size.
There is only 3.63GB in a phone with 8GB memory ,and there is only 1.3GB in a phone with 3GB memory.
Is there any way to break the limit?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the use of zero copy buffers. Map buffers without copy overhead and un-map buffers that are not in use. This way you are still limited to CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE bytes of memory but unused buffers won’t take up space.

Arm has an OpenCL extension which allows direct memory import into OpenCL: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/extensions/arm/cl_arm_import_memory.txt